# SD Card not recognized in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, sd-card, toshiba-laptop, device-manager

I'm running Windows 8.1 (x64) on a Toshiba L505D-S5965 and whenever I insert my SD card into it, I get an error that states "USB device not recognized". I'm pretty sure this isn't a hardware error since it randomly worked for a bit after a reboot, and then stopped.

In Device Manager, under Universal Serial Bus controllers, there's a device that's a "Unknown USB Device (Device Descriptor Request Failed)" with a Code 43 (Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems), and another hidden one with the same name and a Code 45 (Currently, this hardware device is not connected to the computer). Under Disk Drives, there's a hidden "SDXC Card" device that gives a Code 45, and under Other devices, there 2 "Unknown Drives" that give a Code 28 (The drivers for this device are not installed) and might be related to the SD problem.

How do I fix this problem? I've tried installing the drivers a few times, but should I run the driver installation in compatibility mode (since this laptop was upgraded a few times)?

EDIT: The problem lies in "Unknown USB Device (Device Descriptor Request Failed)"

Comment: Do you have another computer to plug the drive into? Have you gone to the computer brand support website and downloaded and installed updated drivers?

Comment: I have tried to install updated drivers but I would always get an error that the drivers aren't x64 bit drivers (even though they are). And I have tested the SD on other computers and they work.